# .NET AMQP Messaging Pattern Issues

Tags: c#, events, rabbitmq, messaging, eai

I have created a small class using RabbitMQ that implements a publish/subscribe messaging pattern on a topic exchange. On top of this pub/sub I have the methods and properties:

1. void Send(Message, Subject) - Publish message to destination topic for any subscribers to handle.
2. MessageReceivedEvent - Subscribe to message received events on this messaging instance (messaging instance is bound to the desired subscribe topic when created).
3. SendWaitReply(Message, Subject) - Send a message and block until a reply message is received with a correlation id matching the sent message id (or timeout). This is essentially a request/reply or RPC mechanism on top of the pub/sub pattern.

The messaging patterns I have chosen are somewhat set in stone due to the way the system is to be designed. I realize I could use reply-to queues to mitigate the potential issue with SendWaitReply, but that breaks some requirements.

Right now my issues are:

- For the Listen event, the messages are processed synchronously through the event subscribers as the listener runs in a single thread. This causes some serious performance issues when handling large volumes of messages (i.e. in a back-end process consuming events from a web api). I am considering passing in a callback function as opposed to subscribing to an event and then dispatching the collection of callbacks in parallel using Task or Threadpool. Thread safety would obviously now be a concern of the caller. I am not sure if this is a correct approach.
- For the SendWaitReply event, I have built what seems to be a hacky solution that takes all inbound messages from the message listener loop and places them in a ConcurrentDictionary if they contain a non-empty correlation guid. Then in the SendWaitReply method, I poll the ConcurrentDictionary for a message containing a key that matches the Id of the sent message (or timeout after a certain period). If there is a faster/better way to do this, I would really like to investigate it. Maybe a way to signal to all of the currently blocked SendWaitReply methods that a new message is available and they should all check their Ids instead of polling continuously?

  ---

### Update 10/15/2014

After much exhaustive research, I have concluded that there is no "official" mechanism/helper/library to directly handle the particular use-case I have presented above for *SendWaitReply* in the scope of RabbitMQ or AMQP. I will stick with my current solution (and investigate more robust implementations) for the time being. There have been answers recommending I use the provided RPC functionality, but this unfortunately only works in the case that you want to use exclusive callback queues on a per-request basis. This breaks one of my major requirements of having **all** messages (request and reply) visible on the same topic exchange.

To further clarify, the typical message pair for a *SendWaitReply* request is in the format of:

- **Topic_Exchange.Service_A** => *some_command* => **Topic_Exchange.Service_B**
- **Topic_Exchange.Service_B** => *some_command_reply* => **Topic_Exchange.Service_A**

This affords me a powerful debugging and logging technique where I simply set up a listener on **Topic_Exchange.#** and can see all of the system traffic for tracing very deep 'call stacks' through various services.

### TL; DR - Current Problem Below

Backing down from the architectural level - I still have an issue with the message listener loop. I have tried the *EventingBasicConsumer* and am still seeing a block. The way my class works is that the caller subscribes to the delegate provided by the instance of the class. The message loop fires the event on that delegate and those subscribers then handle the message. It seems as if I need a different way to pass the message event handlers into the instance such that they don't all sit behind one delegate which enforces synchronous processing.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say why your code is blocking without a sample, but to prevent blocking while consuming, you should use the EventingBasicConsumer.

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer;
consumer.Received += (s, delivery) => { /* do stuff here */ };
channel.BasicConsume(queue, false, consumer);
```

One caveat, if you are using autoAck = false (as I do), then you need to ensure you lock the channel when you do channel.BasicAck or you may hit concurrency issues in the .NET library.

For the SendWaitReply, you may have better luck if you just use the SimpleRpcClient included in the RabbitMQ client library:

```
var props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
// Set your properties
var client = new RabbitMQ.Client.MessagePatterns.SimpleRpcClient(channel, exchange, ExchangeType.Direct, routingKey);
IBasicProperties replyProps;
byte[] response = client.Call(props, body, out replyProps);
```

The SimpleRpcClient will deal with creating a temporary queue, correlation ID's, and so on instead of building your own.  If you find you want to do something more advanced, the [source](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/master/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/messagepatterns/SimpleRpcClient.cs) is also a good reference.